# cPanel / CentOS now showing strange symbols and exim using 99% CPU

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, exim

Has anyone got any idea why this is happening?

cPanel v72.0.10
CentOS 7.5

Everything is showing as symbols, even "top" in Terminal seems to display some strange symbols.

Exim was using 99% of CPU at the time, but I've killed it. Logs don't show anything strange other than this in the panic log:

```
2018-07-25 14:00:36 Can't cleanup environment
2018-07-25 14:00:39 1fiJPA-00018s-SY failed to unlink /var/spool/exim//msglog/A/A�6*s'�5�QOb�@2�: No such file or directory
2018-07-25 14:01:24 1fiJPt-00018p-Ri failed to unlink /var/spool/exim//msglog/t/: Is a directory
```

[Click here to see the symbols (process list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnPYD.png)

**Update:** Rebooted the server and now it won't come back up. This isn't looking good...

Comment: Looks like file system corruption.  Run `fsck -y` on your main partition.  You're probably going to lose data.  Restore what you can from backups.

Comment: Thanks, this is a VPS so I've made backups and have the hosting company investigating the server. Hopefully the hardware node is okay!